# php image upload in database

Tags: php, image-uploading

error in

```
INSERT into 'cd' (`id`,`image`) 
VALUES ('1',LOAD_FILE('image/1.png')) == ---->
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''cd' (`id`,`image`) VALUES ('1',LOAD_FILE('image/1.png'))' at
>   line 1

Answer (score 1):

You should use backticks instead of quotes `'` around your tablename (`cd`)

Backticks are most likely to be find on the top left of your keyboard (above the TAB), but this can be different for different keyboard-layouts.

Comment: The OP already used the backtick for the columns, you can assume he knows where it is.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Not really... Could be he is editing existing code and copied the backtick... My clarification is also there for other people looking for an answer to this question, so they know where to find it ;)

Comment: still got an error image cannot be null

Comment: Than MySQL probably can't located the imagefile in question `image/1.png`. The relative path probably can't be found, so try to use an absolute path to the image.